# how to left and right reverse camera preview on android?

Tags: android, matrix, camera

I want in origin camera preview screen, left and right reverse camera preview.

I think use `Matrix`

first, show camera preview part. `GLFragment.class`

```
private GLStreamView streamView = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View fragment =inflater.inflate(R.layout.gl_view, container, false);

    stream = (GLStreamView) fragment.findViewById(R.id.gl_stream);
    ...

    return fragment;
}
```

`Stream` is camera preview screen.

and gl_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:padding="0dp"
             tools:context="kr.co.test.video.GLFragment">
        <kr.co.test.video.GLStreamView
            android:id="@+id/gl_stream"
            android:layout_width="480dp"
            android:layout_height="480dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <FrameLayout>
```

I want to say left and right reverse camera preview.

so, I try use `Matrix`

but I don't know how to use matrix.

is it right using a matrix?

please, how to use left and right reverse camera preview screen.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

through *onPreviewFrame* can get the yuv frame, maybe you can trans yuv to matrix and the reverse the matrix , i'm not sure about that. but you can use OpenGL ES to
draw the texture, and reverse it through *shader*

Comment: thanks, Can you help me with other questions?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117195/how-to-use-matrix-camera-preview-left-and-right-reverse-on-android?noredirect=1#comment69438448_41117195